# How to extend the existing mouse cursor in Windows app with some additional little image indications (may be multiple ones) based on the context?

Tags: c++, user-interface, mfc, cursor, mouse

As an example, imagine a complex snap operation, consisting of two active snappings in a context. Here two indicators on the second image show, that we are snapping perpendicularly and that we are snapping to any point of the line. When we drag out from the snapping intersection, we are not snapping to a point anymore, but we are still snapping perpendicularly to the reference line. For such and similar situations I would like to extend the cursor with different indicators, based on the context, like on these images.

Is it possible in MFC? Or otherwise in a Windows application?

[image: Snap operation indicators]

Comment: Yes, it is. You can do a [SetCursor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setcursor).

Comment: But - as I understand - for that I would need to create a set of new cursors with different combinations of possible annotations - which is quadratical in the numbers of them. I don't want to do it. I just want to append the list of chosen annotations to the existing cursor bitmap.

Comment: How many indicators do you have? I don't think you can arbitrarily increase the size of the cursor. I would suggest to look into creating a "DragImage" instead.

Comment: Another idea - use a custom-drawn tracking tooltip control

Answer (score 0):

Extending the cursor is not supported, you can only [load one](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-loadcursorfromfilea). So the best approach is to create all the cursors as .CUR files and then load them as needed.

Answer (score 0):

Cursors can be created programmatically in Win32. The [**CreateCursor()**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-createcursor) function creates a cursor taking its dimensions, its hot spot and its AND (black) and XOR (invert) masks as parameters. Therefore you can create or load the basic pointer cursor masks and then add the indicators (either draw them using GDI, if they are simple, or load them from resources), creating the additional cursors you may need. I think it's a quite heavy job to do all these on the fly, so it would best to create all possible indicators during initialization.

The `CreateCursor()` function seems to create only monochrome cursors, maybe the [**CreateIconIndirect()**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-createiconindirect) function can create color cursors. Also take a look into this Win32 documentation topic: [**Using Cursors**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/menurc/using-cursors).

Of course this is quite an amount of work. You decide if it's worth or not...